# Trouble w/ Callback Function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble actioning a callback function in one of my React classes.  Basically I call `checkSource` on click and then if it meets a specific requirement I want to call `handleSubmitClick`.  I have a feeling this has to do with me calling `this.handleSubmitClick`, but I don't understand.  My understanding is that the `this` is referring to the component object that I created.  If this is the case, shouldn't it just call that function and execute?

The full component is here:

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  handleTextInput: function(event){
    this.setState({text: event.target.value})

  },
  checkSource: function(){
    var clientId = 'xxxx';
    var resolve = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=';
    $.get(resolve + this.state.text + '&client_id=' + clientId, function(data) {
      $.get('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/' + data.user.id + '/?client_id=' + clientId, function(data) {
        if(data.followers_count < 3000) {
          console.log("handleSubmitClick now");
          this.handleSubmitClick();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  },
  handleSubmitClick: function() {
    console.log('handleSubmitClick going')
    console.log(this.state.text)
      var linkStore = this.props.linkStore
      linkStore.push(this.state.text)
      this.setState({text: ''})
      this.props.handleListSubmitClick(linkStore)
      console.log(this.props.linkStore)

  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div className="text-center">
          <h1>Soundcloud3k</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="input-group">
          <input
            onChange = {this.handleTextInput}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search fr..."
            value={this.state.text} />
          <span className="input-group-btn">
            <button
              onClick={this.checkSource}
              className="btn btn-default"
              type="button">Submit!</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }


});
```

This is the render function with the `checkSource` call

The console logs for the `checkSource` function works as intended, but I can't get the `handleSubmitClick` to do anything.  I don't get an error or anything in the console.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$.get` callback `this` does not refer to your component, you should set `this` for each callback. Also `return false` in ajax callback does not make sense so you can remove it

```
checkSource: function(){
  var clientId = 'xxxx';
  var resolve = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=';

  $.get(resolve + this.state.text + '&client_id=' + clientId, function(data) {
    $.get('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/' + data.user.id + '/?client_id=' + clientId, function(data) {
      if(data.followers_count < 3000) {
        this.handleSubmitClick();
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
},
```